# Как поменять атрибут href у кнопки "Ответить" в комментариях WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

При использовании функции

```
<?php wp_list_comments(); ?>
```

WordPress генерирует список комментариев к статье, при этом для каждого комментария есть кнопка-ссылка "Ответить".

Очень нужно изменить (можно удалить вообще) атрибут href средствами WP.

Comment: А чем он вам мешает, этот href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам это не нужно. Потому что href там необходима принципиально, для функциональности. Она содержит либо id комментария, на который вы отвечаете, либо ссылку на страницу входа. Если вы удалите href, то ответ не будет отнесён к комментарию, и просто станет ответом на пост. Вы потеряете всю иерархию будущих комментариев.

Предположу, что запрос вызван требованиями очередного СЕО-шника, который не знает, как посмотреть, что эта ссылка имеет `rel="nofollow"` или не понимает, что это такое. Отправляйте таких специалистов подальше.

Ну, а если понадобится внести другие изменения с кнопку "Ответить", то следует использовать фильтр `comment_reply_link`.

```
/**
 * Фильтр кнопки Ответить на комментарий.
 *
 * @param $html string html-код кнопки Ответить
 * @param $args array Массив аргументов.
 * @param $comment object Объект комментария.
 * @param $post WP_Post Пост.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function comment_reply_link_filter( $html, $args, $comment, $post ) {
    // Ваш код, изменяющий $html кнопки.

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'comment_reply_link', 'comment_reply_link_filter', 10, 4 );
```